# how to play .mov file in a browser without 3rd party addon

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, mov

I'm just curious that how can a .mov file play in a browser without any plug in support.I know that .mp4,.ogg and .webm filescan play without any plug in because the html5 video tag support them.but is there any method that i can display a .mov file in the same way using javascript or anything without use of a 3rd party addon??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short no, you will need a quicktime plugin installed on the client or include a 3rd party library on the page.

Comment: no i'm asking without any 3rd party plugin in the client side.how can i play .mov files in the browser?

Comment: As the now deleted answer said you can do this with the HTML5 video tag, but the quicktime plugin needs to be installed (comes installed by default with chrome and firefox AFAIK).